# How can I write the following Javascript code snippet better?

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with lots of variable that needs to get set. I am only using 5 variables to illustrate my issues.

Here is the js snippet :

```
//Make sure everything is empty
var BCode = '', 
    CID = '',
    Journey = '',
    CentreID = '',
    YearOfBirth = '';

//Get the data getVar is just a global function to get data, the data can be "falsy" e.g. "null" "empty" - this is connected to my second question - please see the next block of code.

BCode = getVar('bcode');
CID = getVar('cid');
Journey = getVar('journey');
CentreID = getVar('centreID');
YearOfBirth = getVar('YOB');

//Currently I am not checking if the "BCode", "CentreID" or any other data is "falsy" e.g. "null, empty" etc.

b1 = Bcode
b2 = CID + CentreID
b3 = Journey
b4 = CentreID
b5 = YearOfBirth
```

I am wondering if there's a better way to re-write the JavaScript snippet as I have 100s of variables that have to be set as above?

if my variable `BCode = getVar('bcode');` return a "falsy" value then I want to know how to omit this variable completely - I don't want to write 100s if checks to see if the value is empty. Basically

if `BCode is "empty" or "null"` then I don't want the code `b1 = Bcode` to get executed at all - as if it was never there. Same goes for b2, b3 etc.. Is there a way to deal with above for 100+ variables set/get scenario where value can be falsy?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have an array or other list that contains the variables that need to be retrieved?

Comment: Try to organize your variables as data structures...

Comment: This might probably fit better to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Beside that whenever you have too many variables and conditions in one function, it is normally an indication that this function does more then one tasks and should be divided into individual functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.forEach`, along with an object of key-value pairs representing what data to get inside which variable. You can not define variables directly unless you're in the global scope, and even then, it's still not *that* kind of definition, so use an object instead.

`Object.keys` can behave differently on different browsers meaning the ordering of the keys may not be the same as you defined. If the order matters (it shouldn't) then you'll need to manually write the keys` array, but seeing as you're setting variables the order is likely not important.

```
var variableNames = {
    BCode: 'bcode',
    CID: 'cid',
    Journey: 'journey',
    CentreID: 'centreID',
    YearOfBirth: 'YOB',
}, keys = Object.keys(variableNames),
// This is the object we'll store the "variables" in
Var = {};

keys.forEach(function(dataName, key){
    var data = getVar(dataName);
    // If the data is not falsy (evaluates to true) thad add it to Var
    if (!!data) Var[key] = data;
});

// All of your variables are now accessible from Var
Var.BCode;

// You can also use the bracket syntax for keys that have spaces, dots or other characters that you can't write directly
Var['Variable Name'];
```

If you ***really*** want to use the values like regular variables, and you are working in the global scope (i.e. not inside a function, and all variables can be accessed, for example, from the browser's JS console), then you can set variables directly if you use `window` instead of `Var` in the above code:

```
var variableNames = {
    BCode: 'bcode',
    CID: 'cid',
    Journey: 'journey',
    CentreID: 'centreID',
    YearOfBirth: 'YOB',
}, keys = Object.keys(variableNames);

keys.forEach(function(dataName, key){
    var data = getVar(dataName);
    if (!!data) window[key] = data;
});

BCode;
window['Variable Name'];
```